# Random number game C

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop, do-while, srand

The game works fine my first time through, although; the second time it only gives you two lives... I have tried to change the number of lives but still can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

> // C_program_random_number_game

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

   srand(time(NULL));
   int num1,x = 0;
   char game, cont, replay;

   printf("Would you like to play a game? : ");
   scanf("%c",&game);

  if (game == 'y' || game == 'Y')
  {
    printf("\nThe rules are simple. You have have 5 tries to guess the computers number. \n \n If you succeed you win the game, if you dont you lose the game. Good luck!");
    do
    {
        int r = rand()%5 +1;
        printf("\n\nEnter a number between 1 and 5 : ");
        scanf("\n%d",&num1);
        x++;
        if(num1 > 0 && num1 < 5)  
        {

            do
            {
             if(num1 < r)
                {
                    printf("\nClose! try a little higher... : ");
                    x++; 
                }
              else if (num1 > r)
                {
                    printf("\nClose! try a little lower...: ");
                    x++; 
                }
                scanf("%d",&num1);

            }while(num1!=r && x <3); 

            if(num1 == r) 
            {
                printf("\nWinner! >> you entered %d and the computer generated %d! \n",num1, r);
            }
            else if(num1 != r)
            {
                printf("\nBetter luck next time!");
            }
            printf("\n\nWould you like to play again? (y or n) : ");
            scanf("\n%c",&replay);
        }
            else
        {
            printf("Sorry! Try again : ");
            scanf("%d",&num1);
        }

    }while(replay == 'y'|| replay == 'Y');

}
else if (game == 'n' || game == 'N')
{
    printf("Okay, maybe next time! ");
}
else
{
    printf("Sorry, invalid data! ");
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Try setting an int to 0.  Incrementing it (x++ for example) if they guess wrong.  This would likely be in the inner do-while loop.  If (x == 3) break out.  Your issue is that you need a "break;" statement.  Your do-while is repeating the for-loop forever.  There should be no need for a for-loop at all if I understand what you want.  EDIT:  Also x is always less than or equal to 3 (per what the for-loop says), so checking it in the while() makes no sense.  In reference to "while(num1!=r || x <= 3);"

Comment: Also you print out "you have 5 tries" but state you only want "3"...

Comment: Please format and properly indent your code! There's no point trying to find bugs from source, which tries to mislead and confuse the programmer (by not showing where the loops etc are with proper indentation).

Comment: You also have an extra curly brace below "scanf("%d",&num1);".  And you should use an "&&" instead of an or "||" as well as remove the equals in "<3" in "}while(num1!=r || x <= 3);".  EDIT:  Oh, and you say "enter a number between 1 and 5" but random from 1 to 25...

Comment: Thank you so much man! The little errors were just from changing things  around and making of my mind about things you know how that goes, also thank you for you suggestions and what not man. It's always tough when you look at something for a little to long and it becomes a blur haha a fresh set of eyes always helps thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are all kinds of issues with you code (most of them are minor in terms of programming).  Most of the errors are typos in what you want done via this question and what you printf().

As is, this code will random between 1-25, accept an input of any valid int, see if you matched it, and only give you 5 tries.  (I didn't add error checking to enforce that the input is between 1-25.  That should probably be added.)

I commented my code below with all my changes and went by that you had in the printf()s.

Note:  See my comments above for explanations of my changes since I already pointed them out.  I also formatted it so its a little more easy to read.

Note2:  I did this quickly using an online compiler.  If you find anything wrong with this or not working as you'd like, just comment below and I'll address it.

```
// C_program_random_number_game

#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    srand(time(NULL));
    int num1,x = 0;
    char game, cont, replay;

    printf("Would you like to play a game? : ");
    scanf("%c",&game);

    if (game == 'y' || game == 'Y')
    {
        printf("\nThe rules are simple. You have have 5 tries to guess the                 computers number. \n \n If you succeed you win the game, if you dont you lose the game. Good luck!");

        do
        {
            int r = rand()%25 +1;

            printf("\n\nEnter a number between 1 and 25 : ");
            scanf("%d",&num1);

            do
            {
                printf("r = %d\n", r);

                if(num1 < r)
                {
                    printf("\nClose! try a little higher... : ");
                    x++; //Increment x if wrong guess
                }
                else if (num1 > r)
                {
                    printf("\nClose! try a little lower...: ");
                    x++; //Increment x if wrong guess
                }

                scanf("%d",&num1);
            }while(num1!=r && x < 5); //If x is 5 or more, they ran out of guesses (also, you want an && not an ||)

           if(num1 == r) //Only print "winner" if they won!
           {
               printf("\nWinner! >> you entered %d and the computer generated %d! \n",num1, r);
           }

            printf("\nWould you like to play again? (y or n) : ");
            scanf("\n%c",&replay);
        }while(replay == 'y'|| replay == 'Y');
    }

    printf("Thanks for playing! ");

    if (game == 'n' || game == 'N')
    {
        printf("Okay, maybe next time! ");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a combination of two problems.  The first is that you're not breaking out of the "for" loop when the number matches.  Therefore the match is only checked on every third guess.

The second problem is in this logic check:

```
}while(num1!=r || x <= 3);
```

We see that this turns into "true" if the for loop is broken out of early.